# Javascript function determining number combination with smallest possible difference

Tags: javascript, function, number-sequence

I'm struggling to formulate a Javascript function that would allow me to create 2 numbers out of a user input, according to 2 rules.

```
let userInput;
let num1;
let num2;
```

Rules:
num1 + num2 = userInput and
num1 - num2 must be the smallest positive number possible.

So with a user input of 5 the function should return 3 and 2 for num1 and num2 and not 4 and 1.

Could you please help me formulate such a Javascript function?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Is this a school assignment? Anyway, the min number for 4 is 2, 6 is 3 and 10 is 5? You probably see the pattern here. All you need is to find out if the user input is odd, using modulus (%).

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I swear this is no homework but rather part of my very first web app. I'm learning Javascript on my own so...

Comment: But how do I make my function return 3 and 2 instead of 4 and 1 (as in my example with a user input of 5 above)? The modulus doesn't solve that.

Comment: I mean, how can I tell Javascript to return the num1 and num2 combination with the smallest modulus possible?

Comment: You will always receive smallest possible number if you take almost equal parts of the `userInput`. For exaple, 5/2 = 2.5 => round it to 3(first part), then do 5-3 = 2(second part).

Comment: Wow this looks like it should do what I want. Thank you so much Jay!

Comment: This may have some caveats when the input is a subnorm.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get a notification when you responded. There are numerous ways to solve this, but I would use `Math.ceil()`, that automatically rounds up any decimals, and `Math.floor()` that rounds down.

```js
let userInput = 5;
let num1 = Math.ceil(userInput/2);
let num2 = Math.floor(userInput/2);

console.log(userInput, num1, num2)
```

Another way could be to divide `userInput` by 2 and use `parseInt()` to cut off all decimals, and then add `userInput%2` to that result, resulting in 1 if `userInput` is odd and 0 if even. Subtract `num1` from `userInput` to get `num2`.

```js
let userInput = 5;
let remainder = userInput%2 // 1
let num1 = parseInt(userInput/2) + remainder;
let num2 = userInput - num1;

console.log(userInput, num1, num2)
```

Comment: Thx a lot Rickard! I will try out your solution as well.